# JOOQ date field query consider one day less of the provided date parameters

Tags: mysql, jooq, localdate

I'm having this strange issue where the jooq query on a mysql date field counts one day less than the given parameter.

I have `person` table and I want to query the person created between two dates say `2021-02-01` and `2021-02-05`.

```
mysql> desc person;
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field        | Type                           | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| first_name   | varchar(255)                   | NO   |     | NULL              |                                               |
| created_date | date                           | YES  |     | NULL              |                                               |
+--------------+--------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+    

mysql> select first_name , created_date from person order by created_date desc;
+------------+--------------+
| first_name | created_date |
+------------+--------------+
| john       | 2021-02-05   |
| joe        | 2021-02-04   |
| andrew     | 2021-02-01   |
| mike       | 2021-01-31   |
+------------+--------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I query this with plain sql I get following correct result set

```
mysql> select first_name , created_date from person where created_date between '2021-02-01' and '2021-02-05' order by created_date desc;
+------------+--------------+
| first_name | created_date |
+------------+--------------+
| john       | 2021-02-05   |
| joe        | 2021-02-04   |
| andrew     | 2021-02-01   |
+------------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But when I query this with jooq I get data for the date range `2021-01-31` and `2021-02-04`. That means one day less than the provided parameters

```
jooq.dsl()
.select(Tables.PERSON.FIRST_NAME, Tables.PERSON.CREATED_DATE)
.from(Tables.PERSON)
.where(Tables.PERSON.CREATED_DATE.between(LocalDate.parse("2021-02-01"), LocalDate.parse("2021-02-05")))
.orderBy(Tables.PERSON.CREATED_DATE.desc())
.fetch()

result = {ResultImpl@13870}  size = 3
 0 = {RecordImpl2@13883} "|first_name|created_date|\n+----------+------------+\n|joe       |2021-02-04  |"
 1 = {RecordImpl2@13884} "|first_name|created_date|\n+----------+------------+\n|andrew    |2021-02-01  |"
 2 = {RecordImpl2@13885} "|first_name|created_date|\n+----------+------------+\n|mike      |2021-01-31  |"
```

This is the jooq generated TableField

```
 /**
 * The column <code>person.created_date</code>.
 */
public final TableField<PersonRecord, LocalDate> CREATED_DATE = createField(DSL.name("created_date"), SQLDataType.LOCALDATE, this, "");
```

what am I doing wrong here. Can someone help me

Comment: Please show us the SQL queries that jOOQ generates

Comment: Most likely, it's because of the timezone difference. It seems your DB is defaulting to UTC and your timezone is behind UTC. If you do not mention timezone with `LocalDate`, it defaults to JVM's timezone.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Yes. That was the issue. I set time_zone config in my.cnf and now this is fixed. Thanks!